# Remove Flutter TabBar bottom border

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a custom TabBar using PreferredSize, but I can't meld the color of the TabBar with my body, there seems to be a border between the TabBar and the body. The picture below will show you clearly what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

I have tried to create a border with the same color as the body with large width, but it doesn't seems to work. Here is my code:

```
  Widget _buildAppBar(context) {
return AppBar(
  title: Text(title),
  elevation: 0,
  flexibleSpace: Image.asset(
    'images/motif_batik_01.jpg',
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    width: 1200,
  ),
  bottom: _buildTabBar(context)
);
```

}

```
  Widget _buildTabBar(context) {
return PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
        topRight: Radius.circular(50),
      ),
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
      top: 50,
      left: 20,
      right: 20,
    ),
    height: 100,
    child: TabBar(
      indicator: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.orange, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
      ),
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.orange,
      tabs: <Widget>[
        Tab(child: Text('A', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0))),
        Tab(child: Text('B', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0))),
      ],
    ),
  )
);
```

}

Edit Notes: I figured out that if my 'preferedSize' is a multiplication of 40.0 (40.0, 80.0) the line disappears, could it be a bug in the flutter itself?

Comment: I am quite certain that the border does not come from the `TabBar` itself. Please show where you use `_buildTabBar` function.

Comment: @George I have edited my code shown above, you can check it out.

Comment: Removing the image doesn't work by the way.

Comment: do you think it could be the body of this screen providing this border? I.e. it's not part of the `AppBar`.

Comment: @George the body is only a DefaultTabController and a Container with color, no border is present.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add indicator color to tabBar and color to transparent.

`indicatorColor: Colors.transparent`

Comment: This is perfect. Simple and don't have to worry about Theme color changes in the future.

Comment: The `indicator` and `indicatorColor` doesn't the bottom border that is highlighted on OPs picture. It removes only the moving indicator of the current selected tab.

Comment: Doesn't work. The underline is still present.

Comment: dividerColor: Colors.transparent,

Comment: The answer from @ajaybadole should be added to the answer.

Comment: also add the    dividerColor: Colors.transparent,

Answer (score 37):

Things get nasty if you use Material3 in your app:

```dart
ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    ...
)
```

then all mentioned solutions do not work. If we read a documentation for `TabBar`:

```
  /// The color of the divider.
  ///
  /// If null and [ThemeData.useMaterial3] is true, [TabBarTheme.dividerColor]
  /// color is used. If that is null and [ThemeData.useMaterial3] is true,
  /// [ColorScheme.surfaceVariant] will be used, otherwise divider will not be drawn.
  final Color? dividerColor;
```

So even if we do some tricks, the app choses `TabBarTheme.dividerColor`. I have tried setting that to `null` or to `Colors.Transparent`, but it did not work. Hence, it led me to try with `ColorScheme.surfaceVariant`.

One of the solutions is to create this theme wrapper (parent `Widget`) for your `Widget`:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var theme = Theme.of(context);
  return Theme(
      data: theme.copyWith(
        colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(
          surfaceVariant: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
      child: TabBar(
           ...
      )
    );
}
```

And voila:
[image]

Answer (score 34):

Add divider color to tabBar and color to transparent.

`dividerColor: Colors.transparent`

Answer (score 23):

`indicator:BoxDecoration()` 
 or 
 `indicatorColor:Colors.transparent`

Comment: If you can add a bit more detail in context of the OP's question that would be good :-) That will also make it easier for future community members that find this post.

Comment: Doesn't work. The underline is still present.

Answer (score 5):

Add this line:

```
`dividerColor: Colors.transparent,`
```

inside TabBar() and then hot reload.

Answer (score 3):

whatever you are returning in `body`, wrap it inside below code. dont forget to close bracekts.

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
context: context,
removeTop: true,
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using material3, then you can use this:

```
   indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(borderSide: BorderSide.none)
```

Answer (score 2):

Making the `dividerColor: Colors.transparent` works.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: TopBarDownloads(toptitle: 'New & Hot'),
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      bottom: TabBar(
      isScrollable: true,
      dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
      indicator: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: kBordRadius(30),
        color: Colors.white
      ),
      tabs: const [
        Tab(text: ' Coming Soon',),
        Tab(text: ' Everyone\'s Watching',),
      ]
      ),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(children: [
      buildTabBarView('Coming Soon '),
      buildTabBarView('Everyone\'s Watching')
    ]
    )
  ),
);}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `indicatorWeight: 0`. That'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

In Themedata change useMaterial3 into false , it worked for me

```
useMaterial3: false,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dividerHeight: 0,
```

Set height to `0` works to me

Answer (score 0):

Add the following properties.

```
          indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
          indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          indicatorWeight: double.minPositive,
```

Example:

```
TabBar(
          tabs: widget.tabs
              .mapIndexed((index, e) => _buildTabItem(tab: e, index: index))
              .toList(),
          controller: widget.controller,
          labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
          indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          indicatorWeight: double.minPositive,
          physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

TabBar(dividerColor: Colors.transparent,)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried make the elevation of the AppBar that houses the TabBar to be 0,

```
final topBar = AppBar(
      elevation: 0.0, <------------ here
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      bottom: TabBar(
        indicatorColor: Colors.black,
        indicatorWeight: 2.0,
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
        tabs: [
          Tab(
              child: Text(
            'Tab one',
            style: headerTextStyle,
          )),
          Tab(
              child: Text(
            'Tab two',
            style: headerTextStyle,
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Yea I did, but it only removes the shadow not the border.

Answer (score -2):

añade estas propiedades al

```
TabBar(  indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
            insets: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          ),
          indicatorWeight: 0,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
          labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0), )
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This site is English only, please translate your text. You can also join stackoverflow en Español: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Please note that indicatorWeight: 0 will throw an error --> it must be always greater than 0